# Vimeo advanced API: Filter videos by privacy setting

Tags: vimeo-api

Is there a way to filter the video list by privacy setting? Now there are all videos shown but I only want those set to "anybody". In the Vimeo Playground there is no parameter for this (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getUploaded).

Is it possible to filter this in the call or do I have to filter later in the array? If so, then how is it possible that I always show 15 videos per page?

This is the code I use:

```
$videos_call = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getUploaded',
    array (
        'sort' => 'newest',
        'per_page' => '15',
        'page' => $page,
        'full_response' => true
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering by privacy is not supported in the Advanced API, but it's on the list for the new API (developer.vimeo.com/api).

In the meanwhile, I recommend loading more than 15 on a page, and filtering it down through PHP.

Comment: Is this possible now with the new Vimeo API? I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: We have not yet released this feature, and can not give an estimate as to it's release